# How to calculate proportions in all columns of a df

Tags: r

I have a df that is 24 col x 561 rows.

All columns started as numeric, and I cut them into factor variables with levels "0", "1" and ">1"

For each of the 24 columns, I want to calculate the proportion of ">1" to produce a table that looks something like this

| Variable | Prop >1 |
| --- | --- |
| V1 | 0.2 |
| V2... | 0.8 |
| V24 | 0.3 |

I've tried prop.table(table(df))

Every time I try to apply table to my dataframe, I get the following error:

Error in table(df) :
attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Comment: With tidyverse, you can try something like `reframe(df, across(everything(), ~ sum(. == ">1") / n()))`?

Comment: ... and, in fact, there's no need to convert them to factors in the first place...

Comment: You can't apply table() to a data frame like that. You need to do it for each column. That's the cause of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make some test data

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Row = rep(1:561, times=24),
  Variable = rep(paste0("V", 1:24), each = 561),
) %>% 
mutate(Value = rnorm(nrow(.), mean = 0.5))  %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = Variable, values_from = Value, id_cols = Row) %>% 
select(-Row)
```

Solve the problem.

```
df %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ mean(. > 0.1))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = "Variable",
    values_to = "Proportion"
  )
# A tibble: 24 × 2
   Variable Proportion
   <chr>         <dbl>
 1 V1            0.640
 2 V2            0.677
 3 V3            0.592
 4 V4            0.676
 5 V5            0.665
 6 V6            0.674
 7 V7            0.672
 8 V8            0.654
 9 V9            0.676
10 V10           0.642
# ℹ 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with the code presented is that you don't make a table with a whole data frame, just with the individual columns.

So one table would be.

```
prop.table(table(df$v1))
```

though nowadays

```
table(df$v1) |> prop.table()
```

But that is going to give you all three proportions and hence is not what you want, you just want proportion of v1 > 1.

There are different ways to accomplish what you want and how I'd do it depends on what I want to do with the resulting "table" (in quotes to distinguish from a table object in R). Is that the final product or is the resulting table something that you will want to work with further or are you trying to make something to include in a report?

Let's say it is for a report and you don't want to use one of the nice table making packages.

To get the proportion ">1" for a specific variable, the simplest base R way, assuming no missing values  is

```
sum(df["v1"] == ">1"])/length(nrow(df))
```

You can make a function and use lapply to run it through the list of variable names.

Think of it like this

```
names(df)
sum(df[names[1]] == ">1"])/length(nrow(df))
```

As was mentioned above you wouldn't need to do the recode even if instead of `">1"` you said

```
sum(df[names[1]] > 1])
```

### Option 2

I think an even better option is to reshape your data to long so that you have a column called `varname` and a column called `value` and then use varname as the grouping variable and either `aggregate()` in base R or summarize in tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

Create sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,">1"),24*561,replace=T),ncol=24))
colnames(df) <- paste0("V",1:24)
```

Use `sapply` and `table` functions:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(df,table)[1,]/nrow(df))

V1                        0.3333333
V2                        0.3654189
V3                        0.3297683
V4                        0.3351159
V5                        0.3618538
V6                        0.3172906
V7                        0.3065954
V8                        0.3333333
V9                        0.3137255
V10                       0.3582888
V11                       0.3761141
V12                       0.3475936
V13                       0.3547237
V14                       0.3386809
V15                       0.3244207
V16                       0.3208556
V17                       0.3119430
V18                       0.2852050
V19                       0.3101604
V20                       0.3386809
V21                       0.3458111
V22                       0.3172906
V23                       0.3172906
V24                       0.3244207
```